# How to prove that the product of a countable base is a countable base of the product set?

Tags: general-topology

It is simple but I can't find a elegant way to prove it.

> $(\Omega_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ are metric sets and for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, $\mathcal{W_i}$ is a countable base of the topology of $\Omega_i$.
> How to prove that $\Pi_{1\leq i \leq n}\mathcal{W_i}$ is a countable base of the topology of $\Pi_{1\leq i \leq n}\Omega_i$ ?

Comment: Two parts. That it is countable: If $a_{i,j}$ is an enumeration of $W_i$, then $a_{1,0},a_{2,0},...,a_{n,0},a_{1,1},...,a_{n,1},...$ is an enumeration of the product. That is is a base: It is enough to look at the open sets $U=\prod_{k=1}^nU_k$, where $U_k$ is open in $\Omega_k$. For each $k$ there is some $a_k\in W_k$ such that $a_k\in U_k$. Then $(a_1,...,a_k)\in U$.

Comment: The question is why it is a base, or why is it countable? Anyway, the notation $\prod_i \mathcal{W}_i$ (like a Cartesian product) is not good. One should write $$\mathcal{W} = \{U_1 \times \ldots \times U_n : (U_1,\ldots,U_n) \in \mathcal{W}_1 \times \ldots \times \mathcal{W}_n\}.$$

Comment: @owl Thank you!

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Is there an ambiguity with this notation?

Comment: Yes, it is the notation for Cartesian product i.e. the set of all $n$-uples $(U_1,\ldots,U_n)$ with $U_1 \in \mathcal{W}_1,\ldots,U_n \in \mathcal{W}_n$. But the basis is the set of all Cartesian products $U_1 \times \cdots \times U_n$ with $U_1 \in \mathcal{W}_1,\ldots,U_n \in \mathcal{W}_n$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> $(\Omega_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$ are metric sets and for all $i \in \{1,...,n\}$, $\mathcal{W_i}$ is a countable base of the topology of $\Omega_i$.
> $\Pi_{1\leq i \leq n}\mathcal{W_i}$  of $\Pi_{1\leq i \leq n}\Omega_i$ ?

What we need to prove is that a set $U\subseteq \Pi_{1\leq i \leq n}\Omega_i$ that is open in the product topology can be written as a union of elements of the collection $\mathcal W:=\{A_1\times...\times A_n\mid A_i\in\mathcal W_i\}$.

Let $(x_1...,x_n)$ in  $U$.

On base of the definition of "product topology" we conclude that $\forall i $ $\exists V_i\in \mathcal T_i$ and $x_i\in \mathcal V_i $ where $\mathcal T_i$ are the respective topology of$(\Omega_i)_{1\leq i \leq n}$  : $$(x_1,...,x_n) \in V_1\times...\times V_n\subseteq U$$

Since $\mathcal W_i$ is a base of $\mathcal T_i$ so $x_i\in U_i\subseteq V_i$ for some $U_i\in\mathcal W_i$.

Then we have:$$((x_1,...,x_n) \in U_1\times...\times U_n\subseteq V_1\times...\times V_n\subseteq U$$

We can do this for every $(x_1,...x_n) \in U$ enabling us to write $U$ as a union of elements of the collection:$$U=\bigcup_{(x_1,...x_n)\in U}U_1\times...\times U_n $$ which are all elements of $\mathcal W$ and that show the result    $\square$.

Comment: Very concise, thanks!

Comment: Thanks to you, really good problem